# SupportMapFragment's getMap() returns null

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to create a `SupportMapFragment` dynamically and to put it in a `FrameLayout` container.

My issue is that `mMapFragment.getMap()` returns `null`...

Anybody can help?

**CenterMapFragment.java**

```
public class CenterMapFragment extends Fragment {

    private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.center_map_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity()) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMapFragment == null) {

            mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map, mMapFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit(); 

            setUpMap();
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {       

        GoogleMap map = mMapFragment.getMap();  

        // map is null!

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();     
    }
}
```

**center_map_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_loc"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/locbtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`commit()` on a `FragmentTransaction` does not perform its operations immediately. By the time you call `setUpMap()`, `onCreateView()` will not have been called on the `SupportMapFragment`, and hence there
will not yet be a map.

One approach is to not use nested fragments, electing instead to have `CenterMapFragment` extend `SupportMapFragment`, in which case `getMap()` should work any time after `onCreateView()` (e.g., `onActivityCreated()`).

Comment: If `CenterMapFragment` extends `SupportMapFragment`, how can I set the map to the `FrameLayout`? I have to change the layout?

Comment: @jul: One approach would have `CenterMapFragment` implement an `onCreateView()` that called `super.onCreateView()` first, to get whatever `SupportMapFragment` creates. Then it would create the `FrameLayout` and add the `super`-created `View` as a child of the `FrameLayout`. Then it would return the `FrameLayout` from `onCreateView()`. This wraps `SupportMapFragment`'s content in whatever `CenterMapFragment` wants. Or, have `CenterMapFragment` be just an ordinary `Fragment` and use `MapView` instead of `SupportMapFragment`. Or, find a better time to call `setUpMap()` with your current code.

Comment: @CommonsWare's first approach above is easier than trying to work with MapView directly.  MapView requires that you forward it all lifecycle methods to it and run the MapsInitializer.initialize(...) code yourself.

Comment: extending `SupportMapFragment` and calling super from `onCreateView()` is not working. Still `NullPointerException`~!

Answer (score 2):

In the following link MapView is used as CommonsWare suggests in the last part of his comment:

http://ucla.jamesyxu.com/?p=287

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView m;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflat and return the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
        m = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        m.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        m.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        m.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        m.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        m.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

I hope these will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

is asynchronous, the map won't be ready yet when you return from it. Simply call

```
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

as the next line, that will make it synchronous and will execute it for the next instruction to pick up the finished map all right. If you're worried about the time it takes, put the whole initialization into an `AsyncTask` and show a progress indicator to the user while the map is initializing.