# android getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to load a map with com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment, but I get null in findFragmentById.

My xml fragment file:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    private void selectItem(int position){
        //some code
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MyMapFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

MapFragment:

```
MyMapFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment)  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        //here smf is null
    }
}
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/16322152/1944666

Answer (score 0):

[This is the answer:](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a fragment. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.

And furthermore when playing with nested fragments, use `getChildFragmentManager()`.